# How can I tell what shell is running my init file?

Tags: bash, shell, config, sh, zsh

I have an init file (`/etc/profile.d/which2.sh`) that aliases the `which` command whenever any shell starts. In bash or sh that is fine but in zsh I don't want that as `which` is a built-in that is already aware of aliases and functions. How can I have the script 'know' when it is under zsh and not execute the alias?

`$0` does not help.

I have fixed the problem by simply unsetting the alias in zsh-specific ~/.zshrc, but I would like to know another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
[ "$(which which)" = /usr/bin/which ] && alias which "whichever"
```

This doesn't verify the *name* of the shell; rather it verifies the shell's *behaviour*. That's an instance of a generally-applicable programming paradigm: test behaviour directly whenever possible. (See, for example, browser detection.)

In this case, if you just checked the shell's name as a proxy for a behaviour check, you might luck out now, but things could break in the future. The name is actually arbitrary, and new names might easily be introduced. For example, in some distros `ksh` is a hard-link to `zsh`; `zsh` will adapt its behaviour in an attempt to emulate `ksh`. As another example, I have two different `zsh` versions, one of which is invoked as `zsh5`.

Ideally, the test wouldn't depend on the precise location of the `which` utility, either.

Comment: That does not test the actual shell.

Comment: @Demetri: that is true. It tests the *behaviour* of the shell, so it will work even if your installation renames `zsh` as `z_shell`. But as you please.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the downvote - edit your answer in any way and I will be able to remove it and replace it with an upvote

Comment: @Demetri: OK, took advantage of the opportunity to evangelize "behaviour-not-name" testing.

Answer (score 1):

What are you testing for? In the old days when we had to determine whether we were running under Kornshell or Bournshell, we could do the following test:

```
if [ "$RANDOM" = "$RANDOM" ]
then
    echo "This is the Bourne shell"
    /bin/ksh $*   # Script needs the Kornshell
else
    echo "This is the Kornshell"
fi
```

Of course, both Kornshell and Bash expand `$RANDOM` (and so does zsh)...

Okay... You can find the processes running on the current tty this way:

```
ps -ft $(tty)
```

A little formatting:

```
$ ps -ocommand="" -t$(tty)  
login -pf david
-ksh
bash
```

Pretty good. Shells end with `sh`, so I'll make that assumption. I just want the lines ending with `sh`:

```
$ ps -ocommand="" -t$(tty)  | grep "sh$"
-ksh
bash
```

Yes, I'm running two shells in this TTY. I login with the Kornshell, and shelled out to bash. Let's toss the PID in the mix:

```
$ ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$"
62599 -ksh
62855 bash
```

We want the one with the highest PID

```
$ ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$" | sort -k1,1nr | head -1
62983 bash
```

Yup, I'm running Bash. Let's get rid of the PID:

```
$  ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$" | sort -k1,1nr | head -1 | sed 's/.* //'
bash
```

Let's see if it works with various shells:

```
$ ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$" | sort -k1,1nr | head -1 | sed 's/.* //'
ksh
```

Kornshell is fine.

```
$ ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$" | sort -k1,1nr | head -1 | sed 's/.* //'
zsh
```

Works with zsh

```
$ ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$" | sort -k1,1nr | head -1 | sed 's/.* //'
sh
```

Works with Dash or Ash

```
% ps -t$(tty) -opid="" -ocommand="" | grep "sh$" | sort -k1,1nr | head -1 | sed 's/.* //'
Illegal variable name.
```

Doesn't work in tcsh. Oh well... You can't please everybody.

Comment: Hi. I'm a poor old sod working in circuit design. We are obliged to use csh, otherwise we are submitted to corporal punishments. So I just found out that replacing  `$(tty)` by `${tty}` does the job in this you-shall-not-use-shell csh

Answer (score 0):

[@rici's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19238612/45375) is the most robust and generic solution.

A simpler, `zsh`-specific approach would be to use:

```
# Define a `which` alias only when NOT run by `zsh`.
[ -z $ZSH_VERSION ] && alias which ...
```

---

Some background information on how to **determine the specific shell [binary] that is currently executing**:

A robust option is to call the `ps` utility, relying on the fact POSIX-like shells as well as `csh` / `tcsh` report their own PID (process ID) via built-in variable `$$`:

```
ps -p $$ -o "comm="
```

Note: `ps` implementations differ with respect to what path form they report; e.g.:

- **macOS** reports the binary path *as invoked*, which may be the mere file *name*, the *full path*, or even a relative path; additionally, if the shell was invoked as a *login* shell, such as via `sudo -i`, the mere file name can be prefixed with `-` (e.g., `-bash`).
- by contrast, the `procps-ng 3.3.12` `ps` implementation that comes with **Ubuntu 18.04** only ever reports the file *name*, and never with the `-` prefix.

---

Alternatively, **for scripts that are being *sourced*, as initialization files are, as well as interactive shells, you can examine the value of `$0`**; note, however, that this is **not foolproof**, because the caller may have set `$0` to an arbitrary value.

- It points to the shell binary **as invoked**, i.e., the value may be either a mere filename or a path.
- The value may be prefixed with `-`, namely if the shell is a **login** shell; e.g., `-bash` in a shell started with `sudo -i`.

Note: Do NOT use `$SHELL`, as it only ever reflects the current user's *default* shell. Its value doesn't change even when running other shells later.

Thus, a POSIX-compatible way of obtaining the current shell's executable *filename* is:

```
basename -- "${0#-}"  # -> (e.g., in bash) 'bash'; will NOT work in csh/tcsh
```

Examples:

```
currShell=$(basename -- "${0#-}")  # Store shell-binary filename in variable.

[ "$(basename -- "${0#-}")" = 'zsh' ] && echo "This is a ZSH shell."
```

---

If it is sufficient to **test for a specific shell only**, you may be able to simply test for the presence of specific environment variables such as `$BASH_VERSION`, `$ZSH_VERSION`, or `$KSH_VERSION`.

Note, however, that not all shells have such characteristic variables; `dash`, for instance, does not.

Example:

```
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && echo "This is a ZSH shell."
```

Answer (score -1):

The `SHELL` environment variable contains the full path to the binary of your shell. You could use that (or its basename):

```
s=$(basename $SHELL)
[ "$s" = 'zsh' ] || alias which="what you want it to be"
```

Comment: From what I understand, `$SHELL` is set only once, to the value of the _login_ shell. Thus, `$SHELL` will retain the same value even when running a different shell later - it will NOT necessarily reflect the currently executing shell. Some shells - but not all - set shell-type-specific variables, such as `$BASH_VERSION` or `$ZSH_VERSION`; `dash`, for instance, does not.